# Wordpress - Custom Query for Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added `mentionId` field  on `wp_posts` table on MySQL.

Now, I need to make a query that; "get  posts by mentionId" but couldn't make it with `get_posts()` function on WordPress.

Here is my example code.

```
'posts_per_page' => $_GET["end"]-$_GET["start"],
'offset'         => $_GET["start"],
'orderby'        => 'ID',
'sort_order'     => 'desc',
'meta_key' => 'mentionId',
'meta_value' => '40243'
```

How to include that extra field?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to not to touch the database by adding new fields or tables because you may loose your changes when you update your Wordpress core. The `meta_key` are located at the wp_termmeta table (not recommended to touch!). I suggest you to install [ACF Plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) where you can add `meta_key` values and create a custom query out of it.